# Can I include PHP in an XML file?

Tags: php, html, css, xml, sitemap

I am trying to create an automatic "sitemap.xml", I already followed the instructions provided by [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34657?hl=en) to create one, and here is what I currently have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

        <url><loc>http://www.example.com/</loc></url> 

    </urlset>
```

Now, I wanted to replace "`<url><loc>http://www.example.com/</loc></url>`" with "`<?php include ("assets/includes/menu.inc"); ?>`" which will include the following:

```
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="subMenu"><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="404.php">404 Error Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
```

However, I just realized that PHP include won't work on XML files, so is there anyway to include that php on there?

**What am I thinking of?** I am trying to make my sitemap to be generated/updated automatically, so I want to include my menu "main links" to the XML and then use CSS "before & after selectors" to add the tags `<url><loc>` before every `<a></a>` and `</url></loc>` after, creating: `<url><loc>http://www.example.com/</loc></url>` which is what the sitemap is essentially built of.

Any ideas of how I can make this work?

Comment: If you are using Apache I believe there is a way to specify a file to get parsed through PHP before outputting to the browser no matter what extension it is and you will also have to tell Apache to make sure to send the proper XML headers.

Answer (score 1):

I, personally have never used include when creating a site map but I wouldn't see it as a problem as long as you are using valid xml elements.

You can create your xml using some of the php classes for it and just defining your content type like:
`header ("Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8");`
and from there you can instantiate your xml classes if you chose or do it all by hand

Comment: Do you mean that I can create a php file and then just add header ("Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8"); to the top, and this will make it as XML file?

Comment: yeah pretty much as long as you have valid xml

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is: yes, you can embedded PHP in XML. PHP is specifically designed to be embedded: that's why `<?php...?>` tags exist in the first place. And PHP doesn't know or care where you embed it as long as:

- The file is sent to the PHP interpreter.
- There's nothing in the host document that inadvertently looks like a PHP start tag.

Such answer is basically irrelevant given what you want to do. Google sitemaps are XML files with a very specific syntax. Injecting the HTML code of your main menu will not make a sitemap out of it, just like opening a MP3 file in your text editor and typing your name  in the middle of it will not make Freddy Mercury sing it.