# Why can't I include PHP in XML file?

Tags: php, html, xml, apache

I have the following XML site map structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

        <url><loc>http://www.example.com/</loc></url> 

    </urlset>
```

How can I include "`<?php include ("assets/includes/menu.inc"); ?>`" which have the following:

```
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="subMenu"><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page1.php">Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.php">Page2t</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
```

**What am I trying to do?** I am trying to make my sitemap to be generated/updated automatically, so I want to include my menu "main links" to the XML and then use CSS "before & after selectors" to add the tags `<url><loc>` before every `<a></a>` and `</url></loc>` after, creating: `<url><loc>http://www.example.com/</loc></url>` which is what the sitemap is essentially built of.

Any ideas of how I can make this work?

Comment: You wont be able to do this with CSS. Tools that reads your site map wont care a bit about what CSS you try to apply to it, they just read the raw XML. You will have to make PHP generate all the XML needed for the sitemap.

Comment: Why? Because by default you can't include something in anything else unless the anything else explicitly gives you the means to do so (which in this case it does not). You will have to generate your XML with PHP code, in which case you can do anything. Although I am at a complete loss regarding how CSS comes into the picture at all. And even if it did, you can't insert tags with it.

Comment: I am simply trying to include my menu links to the sitemap file, to make it generated automatically, if I can do that using a .php, do I need .xml? as I heard google needs xml for sitemaps

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I include PHP in an XML file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446337/can-i-include-php-in-an-xml-file)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include XML in your PHP and not the opposite.

Your PHP file must have and XML header content type :

```
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
```

And then you display xml in your php file like this :

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

        <url><loc>http://www.example.com/</loc></url> 

    </urlset>';
```

Keep in mind that you can't simply include html in your sitemap. You have to format your links with specific markup , which can be understood by bots.

Your site map url will be something like http://www.mysite.com/sitemap.php
If the extension of sitemap is really important to you you can get an .xml with url rewriting.
You can also specify the url of your sitemap in robots.txt.

```
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.php
```

See more exemples on this site : 
http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#submit_robots

I'm not really sure what your try to achieve with your CSS because sitemap are meant to be displayed, but usually xml is styled with a XSL

Comment: This will treat the HTML as XML too won't it? Depending on the browser, it won't even try to render any HTML.

Comment: So what? Your sitemap.xml is not meant for browsers …

Comment: Yes for sure but sitemap.xml are not meant for display.

Comment: Hmm, so do you mean I create my sitemap to be .php and then use Apache to make it read as .xml?

Comment: That the content-type that make it read as xml. The extension is not relevant. But if you prefer a xml extension (no technical reason to) you can do it with url rewriting

Comment: Well that's the thing, if sitemap.xml included all this invalid HTML, it won't be how Google and other search engines are expecting it too look like: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en secondly, if you were trying to display the code above on a `sitemap.php`, the browser has already been told it's not a webpage by the `Content-Type`

Comment: You can specify the url of sitemap in robot.txt like this : Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.php. Anyway , including html in your sitemap won't work , it have to use specific markup.

Comment: I am after an auto generated sitemap "for the sake of SEO" that import the site URL's from the website main navigation / menu - which I already include using PHP to all of the site pages. I thought I can also include that php of the menu to my sitemap XML file and then using CSS add before and after tags so I can create "<url><loc>" before and after the url. But apparently I can't. So I can use php and not xml? any ideas please

Comment: It probably can be done with some regexp or DomDocument manipulation , but you should probably ask an other question for that

Comment: What are these mate? so I can't do it the way you recommend in ur answer above?

Comment: As i writed it in my answer , you can't include html in xml. You have to convert your html menu in xml. This can be done with regexp or dom manipulation in php but not with css

Answer (score 0):

The server reads .xml .html .css files as simple text with markup, in order to use php you need to have a .php ( with the default settings, you can modiffy the apache to read every file as php if you want - but that has no sense) and with taht being said, if you want anything which implies php, you need to make a php file that generates the file you need, not the other way around.

The fact that a file has .php extension it tells the server that he must parse that file as php, so the parsers starts and only runs data that is betwen ,while everything else remains untouched.