# XML automatic sitemaps, is it impossible?

Tags: php, html, xml, sitemap

I want to create an XML sitemap (for the sake of SEO), my first attempt to achieve this was by including the website main menu/navigation links using `<?php include ("assets/includes/menu.inc"); ?>`:

```
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
```

To the following XML sitemap file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

        <url><loc>http://www.example.com/</loc></url> 

    </urlset>
```

I already asked a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446337/can-i-include-php-in-an-xml-file) of "How to include PHP to XML" - apparently I can't do that, so my idea was thrown to the bin. I already Googled "How to create an automatic sitemap" but all what I have found was Sitemap Generators which I am trying to avoid.

The question is, is that even possible? to create a sitemap that will pull the links from the website main .inc file? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [`DOM`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) extension installed, you could load the HTML navigation, and then create an XML sitemap.

```
// Create an empty document, load it with your HTML
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML('<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>...');

// Get links
$links = array();
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link){
    $links[] = $link->getAttribute('href');
}
```

Now we have an array of relative URLs in `$links`. You can now generate an XML document using the `DOM` extension (recommended, but more complicated), or use your `$links` directly to generate output:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; // Be wary of "?>" in your document ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <?php foreach($links as $link): ?>
        <url><loc>http://www.mydomain.com<?php echo htmlspecialchars($link, ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8'); ?></loc></url>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</urlset>
```

Comment: And I'd also suggest to use a proper XML library (maybe DOMDocument itself) so there's no need to deal with data escaping and similar dirty stuff.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Agreed.